# Nlog config file causing HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, config, nlog

The application was logging exceptions into a text file. But we decided to use the database to log because the file might become bulky soon. I don't know how to log into DB. so I followed a tutorial https://www.programmingwithwolfgang.com/asp-net-core-logging-to-a-database-with-nlog/  online, everything went fine until I launched the APP then I got this error `HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure`

Each time I remove the nlog.config file, the app will start normally. When I put it back the error will be back. This error is like giving me nightmare

the nlog.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      throwConfigExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="info"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog.txt">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

  <targets>
    <target name="database" xsi:type="Database"  connectionString="${appsettings:name=ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection}">


      <commandText>
        insert into dbo.WebLog (
        Application, Logged, Level, Message,
        Logger, CallSite, Exception
        ) values (
        @Application, @Logged, @Level, @Message,
        @Logger, @Callsite, @Exception
        );
      </commandText>
      <parameter name="@application" layout="AspNetCoreNlog" />
      <parameter name="@logged" layout="${date}" />
      <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
      <parameter name="@callSite" layout="${callsite:filename=true}" />
      <parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception:tostring}" />
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="database" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Enable the internal log and check for errors. See https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Comment: @Julian I got the error log ```Warn Error when setting '${appsettings:name=ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection}' on attibute 'connectionString' Exception: NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Error when setting property 'ConnectionString' on Database Target[database] ---> System.ArgumentException: LayoutRenderer cannot be found: 'appsettings'```

Comment: I have already added the connection string as shown in my code. I read that I can get connectionString directly like this ```connectionString="${appsettings:name=ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection}">```

Comment: The part mentioned above is definitely the problem, I removed it and the app came up

Comment: Change from `${appsettings}` to `${appsetting}`. Just like shown on the wiki: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AppSetting-Layout-Renderer

Comment: @RolfKristensen I removed the 's' as stated but didn't work.  ```connectionString="${appsetting:name=ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection}``` my file is named ```appsettings.json```

Comment: @techstack Then I guess you should use `${configsetting}` (also written in the above wiki-page). See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer

Comment: @techstack I'm guessing with `${appsettings}` then you were thinking about using this external-nuget-package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Appsettings.Standard Remember to update `<extensions>` when wanting to use external nuget-packages.

Comment: @RolfKristensen Thanks this worked. The app is up. Although not yet saving logs to db

Comment: @techstack Maybe time to look again at: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging